# I can't see any file uploaded in my upload folder

Tags: php

When I upload a image file

1. I can't see anything in tmp folder of my wamp server
2. When I execute `move_upload_file` function, no file has been uploaded in my destination folder.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $ext = explode('.',$file['name']);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($ext));
    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf');
    if(in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed)){
        if($file['error']===0){
            if($file['size']<50000){
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).'.'.$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = '\uploads\\'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($file['tpm_name'],$fileDestination);
                header('location:index.php?uploadsuccess');
            }else{
                echo 'size too big';
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'extension incorrect';
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: have you use `enctype=multipart/form-data`

Comment: ok finally I see.

Comment: Also use [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php) to get file extension.

Comment: it is also `tmp_name`, not `tpm_name`.

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

This works on Wamp 3+.

```
Go to wamp folder (wamp/ or wamp64/)
Open wampmanager.conf
Find urlAddLocalhost param and set it on: urlAddLocalhost = "on"
```

There should not be the need to tweak the index.php in www folder.